# css3 is it possible colour change according to width?

Tags: css, css-animations

Please check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6rtnL7a7/

```
.line{
  height:2px;
  width: 200px;
  background:red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
     &:hover:after {
      content: '';
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width: 0px;
      height:2px;
      background:blue;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  &:after {
      content: '';
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width: 0px;
      height:2px;
      background:blue;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-name: back;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

}



@keyframes example {
    from {
      width: 0;
     }
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes back {
    from {
      width: 200px;
    }
    to {
      width: 0;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the confusion.

The animation works fine, but if the line changes to an arrow like this 
https://jsfiddle.net/916er24k/ the width method will not work as the animiation starts from width 0 to 200 width, is there an alternative way to do?

something like colour change from 0% to 100%?

Comment: Do you mean fade the red bar into blue?

Comment: you can use a background (single-color gradient) , background-repeat and background-size or position. could you clarify the question. your demo seems to work.

Comment: This might be possible using gradients and limiting the "steps" in your animation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. updated the questions. Thanks

Comment: is this closer to your needs : https://jsfiddle.net/916er24k/1/   ?  tip: if you set no color on borders, it uses currentcolor from the color rule

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks, yes but want the colour animated like this https://jsfiddle.net/6rtnL7a7/

Comment: i made an answer with mix-blend-mode, but you should use SVG for this :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Many thanks! Is there an SVG example I can learn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mix-blend-mode` could be usable in the futur when IE will understand it. I answer this because of the CSS3 tag

```css
div {
  display: table;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green) no-repeat red;
  background-size: 0;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
div:hover {
  background-size: 100%;
}
.arrow {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.1em white;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  transform: rotate(23deg);
}
.arrow::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  transform: rotate(-23deg);
}
```

```html
hover the arrow .
<div>
  <div class=arrow></div>
</div>
```

IF IE, it doesn't work yet.

SVG should be the thing to do the job

Answer (score 1):

When you say width, do you mean page width? Have you considered media queries?

Try changing your .line width to a percentage, like 75%. Then as the browser window grows or shrinks, the colors change depending on the media query.

```
body {
  padding:4rem;
}

.line{
  height:2px;
  width: 75%;
  background:red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
     &:hover:after {
      content: '';
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width: 0px;
      height:2px;
      background:blue;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  &:after {
      content: '';
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width: 0px;
      height:2px;
      background:blue;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-name: back;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

}

@keyframes example {
    from {
      width: 0;
     }
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes back {
    from {
      width: 200px;
    }
    to {
      width: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .line {
    background:red;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .line {
    background:yellow;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .line {
    background:blue;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/d6d6jegm/

Comment: I think hes asking if an element can have two colors. I'm not sure this is the correct answer.

Comment: He changed his question after I answered. Media Queries will let him change the color. He could easily have the arrowhead one color and the shaft another color.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.line{
  height:2px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #999) no-repeat border-box, linear-gradient(#eee, #777) no-repeat border-box;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  &:hover {
        background-size: 0 100%, 100% 100%;
        transition: all 1s;
  }

}
```